# 相乗りの意味はなんですか。「商品相乗り」「相乗りしたショップ」はなんですか？

Tags: meaning, usage

相乗りの意味はなんですか？

「商品相乗り」、「相乗りしたショップ」とはなんですか？

Comment: 「賞品」ではなく、「商品」とおっしゃりたいのでは？

Comment: そうですね。「商品」ということです。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 5):

この「相乗り」は、ビジネスの世界において比較的よく使われる用語で、「他社と共同で商売をする」とか、「他社に便乗する」という意味になります。

言うまでもなく、この単語のビジネスでの用法は、「車などの乗り物に、他人同士が同乗する」という、「相乗り」の元の意味から来ています。

従って、「相乗りしたショップ」とは、複数の企業（通常は2社）が共同で経営しているショップのことをいいます。

「商品相乗り」は、他社が販売している商品の売れ行きが良いのを見て、それに便乗し、同様の商品を同様の場所や方法で売るという意味になります。

Comment: 確証はないが、Amazon等のECサイトで既存商品ページに出品登録することを`商品相乗り`、それを行う店を`相乗りしたショップ`という意では？
回答者の答えも意味としては成り立つが、そのような意味合いであればシンプルに`コラボショップ`/`コラボ商品`や`便乗商品`とより直接的に表現することが多いです。

Answer (score 2):

相乗り literally means “take a joint ride.” There were a lot of  “相乗りタクシー” waiting in front of railway or subway stations for commuters who return home in the same direction a few decade ago. The driver squeezed five passengers who are quite strangers each other into a car, and the passengers shared the tariff evenly among them.

From this 相乗り is used for an cooperative action such as a joint promotion of a local city and JR, a wine maker and a cheese maker, a pro-baseball team sponsoring newspaper e.g., The Yomiuri and a department store e.g.,Sogo for the team’s winning Japan Series Games under the name of "相乗りキャンペーン - a joint campaign."

When you buy a bunch of 宝くじ – public lottery – jointly with your friend(s) or by group, you are buying the lottery “相乗りで – jointly (with someone).”

Answer (score 1):

相乗りは別々に乗るべき人が一つの乗り物に一緒に乗ることで、同乗することです。Carpoolのような意味です。

ですけど、「賞品相乗り」や「相乗りしたショップ」という言葉は聞いたことはありません。コンテキストを教えてくれたら役に立つと思います。